# A topologically transitive dynamical system without dense orbits

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, ds.dynamical-systems, independence-results

By a *dynamical system* I understand a pair $(K,G)$ consisting a compact Hausdorff space and a subgroup $G$ of the homeomorphism group of $K$.

We say that a dynamical system $(K,G)$

$\bullet$ is *topologically transitive* if for every non-empty open set $U\subseteq K$ its orbit $GU=\{g(x):g\in G,\;x\in U\}$ is dense in $K$;

$\bullet$ *has dense orbit* if for some point $x\in K$ its orbit $Gx$ is dense in $K$.

It is easy to see that a dynamical system is topologically transitive if it has a dense orbit. If the space $K$ is metrizable and nonempty, then the converse [also is true](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/251140179_Existence_of_a_dense_orbit_and_topological_transitivity_When_are_they_equivalent).

On the other hand, under $\mathrm{non}(\mathcal M)<\mathfrak c$, [there exists](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.08800) a subgroup $G\subset S_\omega$ of cardinality $|G|\le\mathrm{non}(\mathcal M)<\mathfrak c$ that induces a topologically transitive action of the Stone-Cech remainder $\omega^*=\beta\omega\setminus\omega$. The dynamical system $(\omega^*,G)$ does not have dense orbits since the space $\omega^*$ has density $\mathfrak c>|G|$. I am interested if such an example can be constructed in ZFC.

> **Problem.** Is there topologically transitive dynamical system without dense orbits?

Comment: Does $S_\omega$ have a dense orbit on $\omega^*$? (Its action is obviously topologically transitive.) I thought I knew the answer to be negative, but I don't see right now.

Comment: By the way the action on the empty set is trivially topologically transitive without dense orbits, so the assertion for $K$ metrizable should assume $K$ non-empty.

Comment: @YCor The action of $S_\omega$ on $\omega^*$ is minimal: all orbits are dense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is yes:

there is a topologically transitive dynamical system without dense orbits.

***Indeed***,

let X be a topological space that is not separable. Let $\ K=X^{\Bbb Z},\ $ and let $\ G\ $ be the group of homeomorphism of $\ K,\ $ induced by shifts $\ s_n\ (n\in\Bbb Z)\ $ of $\ \Bbb Z:\ $

$$ \forall_{n\in\Bbb Z}\forall_{x\in\Bbb Z}\quad
           s_n(x):= x+n $$

Let $\ p:=(p_n)\in K\ $ be arbitrary, and let

$$ P:=\{p_n:n\in \Bbb Z\} $$

Then there exists non-empty open $\ U\ $ in $\ X,\ $ disjoint with set $\ P.\ $ Then non-empty open in $\ K\ $
set $\ W,$

$$ W\ :=\ \pi_0^{-1}(U)\ $$

is disjoint with the orbit $\ p.\ $

On the other hand, let $\ \emptyset\ne G\subseteq K, $
where $\ G\ $ is open in $\ K.\ $ Then there exists
non-empty $\ H\ $ and integer $ a\ge 0\ $ such that
$\ H\ $ is an open subset of $\ X^{(-a)..a}\ $ (*Perl notation* "s..t") and

$$ \emptyset\ \ne\ \pi_{(-a)..a}^{-1}(H)\ \subseteq G $$

Obviously, the orbit of $\ \pi_{(-a)..a}^{-1}(H)\ $, hence of $\ G,\ $ is dense in $\ K.$

***Great!***

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. And what about the case of subgroups $G\subseteq S_\omega$ acting on $\omega^*$?

Comment: @TarasBanakh, you simply overlooked this and I just jumped in. Is $\ \omega^*\ $ simply an infinite countable set (in this context)? And $\ S_{\omega}\ $ the group of all permutations (self-bijections)? For any group which contains the one in the answer, the situation is the same (so simple and nice :) ).

Comment: By $\omega^*$ I denote the remainder of the Stone-Cech compactification of $\omega$ and this is the principal space I am interested in. In this case the group $\mathbb Z$ (and any other countable group) does not work, unfortunately.

Comment: "[...] the remainder of the Stone-Cech [...]" -- no wonder that your mind was far away from any cartesian products. :)

Comment: @TarasBanakh at this point if you're specifically interested in $G\subset S_\omega$ acting on $\omega^*$ it would be worth a separate question.

Comment: Well, the argument shows that if $G$ acts on the discrete set $I$ with no finite orbit and $X$ is an arbitrary topological space then the action of $G$ on $X^I$ is topologically transitive (because by BH Neumann's lemma for every finite subset $F$ of $I$ there exists $g$ such that $gF\cap F=\emptyset$). Next, there are many ways to ensure that there is no dense orbit, e.g., that $G$ is countable while $X^I$ is not separable (which holds if $I$ is nonempty and $X$ non-separable, or if $X$ is non-indiscrete and $I$ has cardinal $>c$).

Comment: @YCor Thank you for the suggestion. I will then accept the answer of Wlod AA and write this specific question separately.

Comment: After all, possibly the Tikhonov embedding into cube may lead to an example, it's to be seen. That would make the Cartesian product a hero again :).

Comment: Taras, thank you (and to YCor :) ) for accepting.

Comment: You are welcome! Thank you for the involvement.